# Cycles rendering problem!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

so I have a problem with both Eves and Cycles rendering. In Eves my banana looks bad, as it looks flat in some areas, this is a high poly model, it has both smooth shading and auto shading, as well as a subSur on 3 and I have tried the SubSur on 6, and I created the texturing in vortex painting.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddW9B.jpg

While in the Cycles render, everything looks good, except the apples are slightly transparent. These apples like the knife have been UV unwrapped, and I painted the texture on from an image. The bowl and cloth were procedurally generated. Although there is no problem with the bowl and cloth, I thought I would mention it, in case it is relevant.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlegC.jpg

So does anyone know why this is happening with the banana in eve and the apples in Cycles?

I plan on baking the high poly banana to a low poly in the end, as the scene will have multiple objects, and I don't fancy waiting until next year to render. It feels like eve is faster at rendering, but cycles looks better. So I would rather fix both issues, and then I will A, know why this is happening in the future, and B, gives me options on what to render in.

Thanks.

Comment: For the banana, it's likely you have a different Subdivision Surface Value for your Render than you do for your Viewport. For the apples, is there any chance you have and alpha value of <1 for the apple texture?

Comment: So yeah, I must have moved the alpha when tinkering with the apple getting it to look right, thanks for that.

As for eve, this is the low poly vs high poly, the high poly still looks more blocky that the low poly. As for the render setting. I tested it on 1 through 4 and it is still the same and 5 and 6 crashed blender :(
https://imgur.com/naPolFe
this is a render in eve with the low poly on the left and the high on the right, and the low poly surface looks better than the high poly. I just went nuts with the high poly vertices, so I could paint finer detail on it.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)